# How to graph git branches

Tags: git

I'm not sure if graphing is what I need but I think it is.

I have a rather large proliferation of git branches, I want to slim this down by deleting old branches, and merging branches that can be merged and so on, but looking at them I can't quite remember which is which.

Is there a way to graph the branches so  I can for example, branches by date, or how branches differ and so on?

I'm sorry if I'm not being clear, It's a little hard to describe exactly what I'm after.

Comment: Are you using a tool such as SourceTree on the client side, or Bitbucket on the server side?  They provide tools for visualizing Git branches.

Comment: just plain terminal git, I don't use GUI.

Comment: `git branch --merged` and `git branch --no-merged` may be useful

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort your branches based on recency,

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/heads/
```

Delete the branches which are old. I use it personally for the same purpose.

Or better and more readable,

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/
```

To check all the unmerged branches in the current branch,

```
git branch --no-merged
```

For a graphical view of all the branches in terminal, you can use the `git log`'s `graph` option,

```
git log --decorate --graph --oneline --all
```

Comment: Ok, that is SUPER helpful, whilst it doesn't help with de-spagehtifying, It will help with dealing with old stuff.

Comment: I hope it helps now, check update. May be useful to some extent.

Comment: @Thermatix, I, personally, have `git log --decorate --graph --oneline --all` aliased as `git overview`.